# Maximal Interval of Existence for a particular System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider
\begin{align}
x' &= (x^2+y^2)\sqrt{|y|}\\
y' &= \frac{1}{y^{42}+1}+\exp(t)
\end{align}

and let $J \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ denote the maximal interval of existence for the solution satisfying $(x(0),y(0)) = (1,1)$.

> I am asked to proof that $\sup J\leq 1$ and investigate how $(x(t),y(t))$ behaves if $t \nearrow \sup J$.

As a hint I am told to think about $z' = z^2$ for $z(0) = 1$ and look at the maximal interval of existence for this IVP. I did that and found the solution: $z(t) = \frac{1}{1-t}$. In this particular case we have $J = (-\infty,1)$ and $\lim_{t \to 1} z(t) = +\infty$.

Unfortunately I don't see how that might help for the initial problem. I have - after certainly thinking to long about this problem - not even the slightest idea about how to proof $\sup J \leq 1$.

How can this be done? I am thankful for any hint or solution sketch.
(I noticed that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are monotonically increasing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily see $y'\ge e^t>0$ giving for $y\ge y(0)=1$ for $t\ge 0$ and thus
$$
x'\ge x^2\implies x(t)\ge\frac1{1-t}.
$$
Or a little better
$$
x'\ge x^2+1\implies x(t)\ge\tan\left(\frac\pi4+t\right).
$$

Comment: You mean $y \geq 1$ for $t \geq 0$? Otherwise I do not see $y \geq 1$.

Comment: Yes, as the question is for the upper bound.

Comment: Seeing $x(t) \geq \frac{1}{1-t}$ helps. Now I know that $x(t) \to \infty$ if $t \nearrow \sup J$. From this inequality we can also already conclude that $\sup J \leq 1$, right?